# querying to custom field over ACF REST API

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, rest-api

Iam using the "ACF" plugin with "ACF to REST API".
I found a solution for querying a custom field over REST API.

I inserted this into my functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'rest_{type}_query', function( $args ) {
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'my_field',
            'value' => esc_sql( $_GET['field'] ),
        )
    );

    return $args;
} );
```

Url: /wp-json/wp/v2/posts?field=test
The wildcard {type} can be: post | user | comment | attachment | custom post type | taxonomy

This solution is not perfect. Once this code snipped is added, the filter works but if you go to /v2/{type} <-- which usually lists all, this stops working.

Any solution for that?

Comment: you should not be using `esc_sql` like that, `esc_sql` is only to be used in very specific circumstances, most people coding with WP will never need to use it. Otherwise is there a reason you're modifying _all_ API queries, not just the ones that have `field` set? Why not use the existing parameters for meta queries instead of adding a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got that working :)

```
add_filter('rest_myRoute_query', function($args, $request) {
  $fields = array('myCustomField');

  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (! empty($request[$field])) {
      $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'   => $field,
        'value' => esc_sql($request[$field]),
      );
    }
  }

  return $args;
}, 10, 2);
```